# When can we exchange the order of big/little O and function composition

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

From Wikipedia

> Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two functions defined on some subset of the
>   real numbers.
>
> One writes $$
>      f(x)=O(g(x))\text{ as }x\to\infty\, $$ if and only there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such that $$
>     |f(x)| \le \; M |g(x)|\text{ for all }x>x_0.  $$
>
> One writes $$
>      f(x)=o(g(x))\text{ as }x\to\infty\, $$ if and only  for any positive real number $M$,  there exists a real number $x_0$, such that $$
>     |f(x)| \le \; M |g(x)|\text{ for all }x>x_0.  $$

1. I was wondering if $2^{O(n)} = O(2^n)$ and $2^{o(n)} = o(2^n)$ when
   considering them as time complexities for algorithms and $n \in
       \mathbb{N}$.  Or is one is the subset of the other?

   For example, I was thinking what relations are between [the second definition of subexponential complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Second_definition) $2^{o(n)}$ and $o(2^n)$?
2. More generally, what conditions on $h$ (and $f$) can make $h(O(f)) =
       O(h(f))$ where the functions can be defined and take values on
   $\mathbb{R}$?  Or when is one is the subset of the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$2^{f(n)}\in O(2^n)$ for some, but not all, $f(n)\in O(n).$ For example, if $f(n)=n+7$ then $2^{f(n)}=128\cdot2^n\in O(2^n),$ but if $f(n)=2n-1$ then $2^{f(n)}=\frac12\cdot4^n\not\in O(2^n).$

On the other hand, for any $f(n)\in o(n),$ it holds that $2^{f(n)}\in o(2^n)$ and indeed $2^{f(n)}\in o(1.0001^n).$

Comment: Thanks! For the little o part, (1) when $f(n)∈o(n)$, by $f(n)∈o(2^n)$, do you mean $2^{f(n)}∈o(2^n)$ instead? Why? Also, by $f(n)∈o(1.0001^n)$, do you mean $2^{f(n)}∈o(1.0001^n)$? (2) Do you mean $2^{o(n)}⊆o(2^n)$? is there any reason if  $2^{o(n)}=o(2^n)$ isn't true?

Comment: For the big O part, I understand the example you gave and agree with it. In [the first definition of subexponential time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#First_definition), "A problem is said to be sub-exponential time solvable if it can be solved in running times whose logarithms grow smaller than any given polynomial. More precisely, a problem is in sub-exponential time if for every $ε > 0$ there exists an algorithm which solves the problem in time $O(2^{n^ε})$."

Comment: I wonder if "running times whose logarithms grow smaller than any given polynomial" means $\log_2 f \in O(n^k)$, and the part after "More precisely" means $\log_2 f \in O(n^k)$ and $ f \in O(2^{n^k})$ are equivalent? Your example for big O part seems to be a counterexample for $2^{O(n^k)} = O(2^{n^k})$.

Comment: I did mean $2^{f(n)},$ yes (though I suppose what I wrote is also true). I don't know what you mean when you ask " is there any reason if $2^{o(n)}=o(2^n)$ isn't true?".

Comment: Certainly $\log_2 f\in O(n^k)$ is not the same as $f\in O(2^{n^k}).$ For $k$ fixed and $f=4^{n^k}$, the former is true and the latter false.